How to fix `FileExistsError` when using the `--basetemp` flag with `pytest`?
TL;DR - How do you use the --basetemp flag with pytest-mpi?
I am currently trying to run tests dependent on MPI using pytest-mpi. I've made a minimal example
# Standard Library Imports
import os

# Third-Party Library Imports
from mpi4py import MPI
import pytest

# Local Library Imports

# Relative Imports

@pytest.mark.mpi()
def test_mpi(tmp_path):
    ## Initialize MPI
    if not MPI.Is_initialized():
        MPI.init()
    MPI_comm: MPI.Intracomm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    comm_rank: int = MPI_comm.Get_rank()

    ## Write comm info to file
    file_name: str = "rank_{}.txt".format(comm_rank)
    file_path: str = os.path.join(tmp_path, file_name)

    with open(file_path, "w") as file:
        file.write("{}".format(comm_rank))

which I am attempting to run with the command
mpirun -n 4 python -m pytest --with-mpi --basetemp=out -v -k test_mpi

However, it gives the error (with some path names sensored with xxx):
=============================================== ERRORS ===============================================
_____________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_mpi _____________________________________

self = PosixPath('/xxx/out')
mode = 448, parents = False, exist_ok = False

    def mkdir(self, mode=0o777, parents=False, exist_ok=False):
        """
        Create a new directory at this given path.
        """
        try:
>           os.mkdir(self, mode)
E           FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/xxx/out'

/home/usr/miniconda3/envs/hpc/lib/python3.12/pathlib.py:1311: FileExistsError

What is causing this error, and how can I fix it?
Things I've tried:

On the pytest-mpi readthedocs, they mention some 'fixtures' related to temp_path. I'm not really sure what a fixture is and how to use them to be honest, but it looks promising!

There's another code on Github that has a block of code that seems to be getting at this problem, but it didn't work conisstently for 3 processes and didn't work at all with more than 2 processes.


Both of these did not fix the FileExistsError.

First make sure there is no file called /xxx/out. Then double check only one rank (per node if this is a local filesystem) tries do create this directory.

@GillesGouaillardet Deleting /xxx/out before running the test does sometimes seem to fix the issue for two processes, but not for more than two processes (and I would hope that I wouldn't have to delete /xxx/out each time I want to run the test. Any advice?

The way I understand the doc, you should use mpi_tmp_path rather than tmp_path as "argument" of your test_mpi function.
